# How to make this function print 10 prime numbers instead of numbers between 2 to 10

Tags: javascript

It currently prints numbers between 2 and 10.
I tried it with while(n) loop but it doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/xv2qjkm8/6/

```
function prime(n) {
      for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
          document.write(i + " ");
        }
      }
    }

    prime(10);

    function isPrime(k) {
      for (var i = 2; i < k; i++) {
        if (k % i == 0) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: don't increment your loop unless you find a prime.

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to recreate your jsfiddle here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count how many primes you have found, so use the `while(n)` but do not forget to decrease it only when a prime is found.

```js
function prime(n) {
  var i = 2;

  while (n) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      document.write(i + " ");
      n--;
    }
    i++;
  }
}

prime(10);

function isPrime(k) {
  for (var i = 2; i < k; i++) {
    if (k % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go the loop whill run while n is true(0 is false) and everytime we find a prime we decrement n

```
function prime(n) {
          for (var i = 2;n; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
              document.write(i + " ");
              n--;
            }
          }
        }



        function isPrime(k) {
          for (var i = 2; i < k; i++) {
            if (k % i == 0) {
              return false;
            }
          }
          return true;
        }

        prime(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you use a tactic like this to both write to the document and check  for how many numbers have been found by making a separate function

```
function print_primes(array, size) => {
   if (array.length == size) { document.write(array.join(" ")); return true; } 
   return false;
}

function prime(n) {
   let array = [];
   let i = 1;
   while (print_primes(array,n) == false) {
     while (isPrime(i) == false) {
       i++;
    }
    array.push(i);
  }

}

function isPrime(k) {
  for (var i = 2; i < k; i++) {
    if (k % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


príme(10);
```